# Anyone know how to make a multiple choice game in swift playgrounds?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift-playground, playgrounds

I was wondering if anyone knows how to make a multiple choice game in swift playgrounds with SpriteKit? I don't want to move over to UIController because I prefer spritekit, but I can't find any code on how to make one. Any help would be amazing.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Swift playgrounds is intended to be a beginner tutorial. As soon as you outgrow it you should move on to the big boy tools. Don't try to use tools for a task that they aren't meant to fix.

Also you should ask yourself if SpriteKit is really the right fit for the task you want to do. UIKit should be more than enough to create a simple multiple choice game. Try googling "make an iOS multiple choice game" and see if there are any tutorials you can follow along.

Just because you're more familiar with doing something one way doesn't mean you shouldn't break out of your comfort zone. You never grow if you stay in your safe space.

Good luck, get out there and learn!